# Linking up a button through a segue when using material.io

Tags: ios, swift, material-design, material-components, material-components-ios

Im a beginner in swift and I am creating a login screen using Material.io in Swift and my UI looks like this [image: ui].
However i dont see anything on my main.storyboard [image: main.storyboard]
I am used to creating a segue manually and then using

```html
performSegue(withIdentifier: <#T##String#>, sender: <#T##Any?#>)
```

to use the segue but now since i dont see the button i'm unable to use the segue on clicking the 2 buttons Login and Register.

Also, usually from main.storyboard you have an IBOutlet or IBAction block to trigger certain features such as do something on a button click.
How does that work when you use MDCButton for instance. How do you link up the button to an action such as trigger a segue or update a text field.
Thank you.

I have declared my button like this

```html
 let nextButton: MDCButton = {
        let nextButton = MDCButton()
        let containerScheme = MDCContainerScheme()
        nextButton.applyTextTheme(withScheme: containerScheme)
        nextButton.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
        nextButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        nextButton.setTitle("CREATE NEW ACCOUNT", for: .normal)
        nextButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didTapNext(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        return nextButton
    }()
```

And i am calling it like this

```html
 @objc func didTapNext(sender: Any) {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toRegistration", sender: self)
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

I have a segue linking the 2 view controllers.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see your code and don't have enough rep to comment, but it looks like you are building your view programmatically. To see when the button receives `touchUp` as you would from an outlet, you need to add a target. Try something like this:

```
func functionWhereYouCreateTheButton() { (PROBABLY YOUR VIEW DID LOAD)
   let loginButton = UIButton()...
   ...
   ...
   ...
   loginButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.buttonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
}

func buttonTapped() {
   self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "SEGUEID", sender: self)
}
```

Comment: i updated the description above and i feel i am doing as you have mentioned. Could you please have a look. Thank you

Comment: @mridulghanshala I think calling `dismiss` is causing the issues. Have you tried it without that? Also have you tried adding a `print` statement in `didTapNext` to see if the button is calling that function?

Comment: do u think if i created 1 view manually and 1 from storyboard and link the 2 up through a segue i am going the right way or i should do something like performnavigation

Comment: I'm don't understand. What view is manual and which is storyboard?